# Range Of Object _Global Failed

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel VBA and I have been struggling to debug the following error:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Dim m As Range
   FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   For Each m In Range("MRF", "FinalRow")
       ComboBox1.AddItem (m.Value)
   Next
Sub End
```

I would like my `ComboBox` to be initialized with the values from `MRF` `Column`. It would take time to initialize if my `For` code is: `For Each m In Range("MRF")`. Now I have an error on the `For` code.

I want the final output of the code to be initialize the `ComboBox` value from the `MRF` `Column`. What I did wrong?

Comment: `For Each m In Range("MRF1:MRF" & FinalRow)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `For Each m In Range("MRF1:MRF" & FinalRow)` i.e. get rid of the `"` quotes around `FinalRow`. Otherwise you're literally inputting the word "FinalRow" which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim & Jean !!!! It Worked!!!But When I Run The Userform I Can't See The Values But THe Values Have Been Initialized. I'm Saying This Based On The Scroll Up & Down On The ComboBox

Comment: With the fix pointed out by Tim and Jean, the code works. What do you mean by you can't see the values?

Comment: L42 : The combobox actually scrolls up and down , i'm not sure whether it fetched the values or not. Its blank.

Answer (score 1):

Why loop? You can pass the Range values directly.

```
Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName"). _
    Range("MRF1:MRF" & FinalRow))
```

or if you want to stick with the loop:

```
For Each m In Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Range("MRF1:MRF" & FinalRow)
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem (m.Value)
Next
```

Comment: Will Try Your Method Now.

Comment: Its Still The Same. The Values Are Being Fetched By Its Blank

Comment: Are you sure your Column MRF have values? MRF almost midway of excels entire column. Or maybe your CB font color is white?

Comment: There Are Values  And The CB Font Color Is Black!!

Comment: did the same but no change! Is there  a way i can send u a screenshot. Because the site wont let me post an image until i reach a reputation 10.

Comment: Out of curiosity i tried  to insert the data into the sheet for the mrf chosen, thinking that the font color is white. The output would be placing the entered data on the next blank mrf row.